# textRange MoveToPoint() IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Have a problem with moveToPoint() method of textRange IE11;

Seems like it dosen't work if pointed node wasn't in first screen;

```html
document.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
 var x = e.clientX; 
 var y = e.clientY; 
 var range = document.body.createTextRange();
 range.moveToPoint(x, y);
 range.expand('word');
 console.log(range);
 console.log(range.text);
});
```

This code grab words from click point, but it wokrs normal only if we clicking in node's that were on first scroll.

If we scroll little bit down to the node that wasnt in first scroll, we will catch the exeception.

Does anybody know how to handle this situation correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, inspired by @dinalt and @JAYBEkster, I came up this solution. Maybe someone will need this after all.

Code below(for IE, didn't check all versons, but it works fine 11+) grab word in complex nested html.

Step bys step how it works:

1. Firstable we create range from e.target
2. We collapse it to the begining.
3. That will be awesome if we just could expand("word") and iterate every each word, but unfortunantly we cant. So we loop through characters split them to words and compare their bounding's with e.clientX, and Y, in the other hand by iterating charakters insted of words we get more control.
4. We get correct one and split target.innerText with it, to get left and right part of node's text.
5. After that we split each part again but this our separators (regexp with all white spaces and word separaters i could imagine) and we get two arr's.

Why we do steps 4 and 5? Cause we find some text that end's in that node, but it may not be the end or start of ther word, for some styling reasons, acent part of ther word my bein it's own node and target.node my just be the middle part of the word. So we have to jump up throug node's and find word's ending.

If u sure that ur html dosen't complain that u can skip all other steps.

6. Then if arr is empty we run our recursive function that runs throug node's and grab's text until find separator.

Yeah it really look like roket since for such, that we mayed think simple task.
But I actualy couldn't find a better solution, There are was a couple of options, bu all of them wasnt's as universal as I need it to be.

Benefits of this code that it really dosen't care about complexivity of html at all.

I will post here the link to my github repositiry where u can find the full code of wordGraber, that will work this Chrome, Safari, FF and IE of course.

https://github.com/6graNik/wordGrabber

Below is just a part for IE.

```js
function getWordFromEventIE(e) {
  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;
  const innerText = e.target && e.target.innerText;
  const separators = /([\s&^:;,!?(){}])+/;
  const IErange = global.document.body.createTextRange();

  try {
    IErange.moveToElementText(e.target);
    IErange.collapse(true);

    let wholeSentenceLength = 0;
    const reqIEcharTest = () => {
      do {
        IErange.expand("character");
        wholeSentenceLength += 1;
      }
      while (!separators.test(IErange.text.slice(-1)) && wholeSentenceLength <= innerText.length);
      const {boundingLeft, boundingTop, boundingWidth, boundingHeight, text} = IErange;

      if (boundingLeft <= x && x <= (boundingLeft + boundingWidth)
       && boundingTop <= y && y <= (boundingTop + boundingHeight)) {
        if (wholeSentenceLength <= innerText.length && !separators.test(text.slice(-1)) ) {
          return text;
        }
        return text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
      }
      IErange.collapse(false);
      return reqIEcharTest();
    };
    const text = reqIEcharTest().trim();
    const innerTextArr = innerText.split(text);
    const innerTextLeft = innerTextArr[0].split(separators);
    const innerTextRight = innerTextArr[1].split(separators);

    let leftPart;
    if (innerTextLeft <= 1) {
      leftPart = recursionWordGet(e.target, 'left') + innerTextLeft.slice(-1)[0];
    } else {
      leftPart = innerTextLeft.slice(-1)[0];
    }
    let rightPart;
    if (innerTextRight <= 1) {
      rightPart = innerTextRight[0] + recursionWordGet(e.target, 'right');
    } else {
      rightPart = innerTextRight[0];
    }

    return leftPart + text + rightPart;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> text', err);
  }
}


function recursionWordGet(target, option) {
  const separators = /([\s&^:;,!?(){}])+/;
  const uniqString = Date.now();

  target.setAttribute("data-target", uniqString);
  const {parentNode} = target;
  const copyNode = parentNode.cloneNode(true);

  copyNode.querySelector(`[data-target="${uniqString}"]`).innerText = uniqString;
  const tagName = copyNode.tagName;


  const text = copyNode.innerText;
  const textArr = text.split(uniqString);
  const textLeftPartArr = textArr[0].split(separators);
  const textRightPartArr = textArr[1].split(separators);

  if (option === 'right') {
    let returnText;
    if (textRightPartArr.length <= 1 && tagName === 'span') {
      returnText = textRightPartArr[0] + recursionWordGet(parentNode, 'right');
    } else {
      returnText = textRightPartArr[0];
    }
    return returnText;
  }

  if (option === 'left') {
    let returnText;
    if (textLeftPartArr <= 1 && tagName === 'span') {
      returnText = recursionWordGet(parentNode, 'left') + textLeftPartArr.slice(-1)[0];
    } else {
      returnText = textLeftPartArr.slice(-1)[0];
    }
    return returnText;
  }

  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use offsetX, offsetY properties.
Or you can add scroll position to x and y vars, using scrollLeft and scrollTop properties of parent element.

Comment: Thanks Denis, already tried that, didn't help, and docs says offset relative to window corners not page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms536632(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that such a bug exists in IE11. You can find details here in comments: http://generatedcontent.org/post/69213745095/ie11review-part1

Possible solution (after you create a range):

```
range.moveToElementText(e.target);
range.collapse(true)
range.expand("word")
```

Now you have the first word selected. You have to check now if the selected word fits your mouse click position using TextRange properties boundingHeight, boundingWidth, boundingLeft and boundingTop. If it doesn't, you move in cycle to the next word:

```
range.collapse(false);
range.expand("word");
```